Fragmented urls in msal authorization code flow, and after authentication, code is not coming as query params
Confiuration code:
function fetchAzureMSALInstance() {
    let azureMsalConfig = {
        auth: {
            clientId: 'e154806f-ba69-417f-a60c-b1c89b2ffa01',
            authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common',
            redirectUri: `${window.location.origin}`
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage', 
            storeAuthStateInCookie: false 
        }
    }
    return new msal.PublicClientApplication(azureMsalConfig)
}

I have a button in the Teams.vue file, and when I click on it:
reviewPermissions() {
`const accessTokenRequest = { scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"], account: self.msalAccount }
    self.azureMsalInstance
        .acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest)
        .then(response => {
            console.log('Login successful', response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            //Acquire token silent failure, and send an interactive request
            if (error instanceof AuthError) {
                //use loginPopup for token, loginRedirect for code
                self.azureMsalInstance
                    .loginRedirect(
                        {
                            scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"],
                            prompt: 'consent',
                            response_type: 'code',
                            response_mode: 'query'
                        }
                    )
                    .then(function (accessTokenResponse) {
                        // Acquire token interactive success
                        let accessToken = accessTokenResponse
                        self.userAccount = accessTokenResponse.account
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        // Acquire token interactive failure
                        console.log(error)
                    })
        }
    })
        
},`

}

My issue is that my product has fragmented URLs, and I cant go and change it simply. I have to work by it. I need to redirect my successful authentication to https:localhost:8080/#/teams (temporary URL) and it would add https:localhost:8080/#/teams?code={CODE} like this ideally. But currently, it adds
https://localhost:8080/#/code=0.AW4A5AR-DlurFE65uFJDKf4ddG-AVOFpun9BpgyxyJsv-gFuAIU.AgABBAIAAAApTwJmzXqdR4BN2miheQMYAgDs_wUA9P_joXDqKpXZKp9lIwysG7256qw7dZV1d_oKavvy6M2VRONZrnpUh`, now my application does not have a route with https://localhost:8080/#/code
Even lets assume that I give redirectUri like https:dev/teams, it will still attach code like https:dev/teams/#code....
Summarizing problems: 1. I want to use fragmented URLs.  2. code is not coming in as ?code query params  My backend wants code, and not token, so I need to go with loginRedirect Approach

The redirect URL is always hardcoded and you can't add any query parameters to it. Also, you can never pass any fragment data like https:dev/teams/#code.... to the server (using #) the things after the # always stays in the browser.
The alternative is if you somehow can pass it into the state parameter, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/msal-js-pass-custom-state-authentication-request
I also blogged about the state parameter here https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/
